Independent random variables with $X^2 + Y^2 =1$
Does there exists independent non-constant  random variables with $X^2 + Y^2 =1$?  I think not because intuitively if there is a relation between them it must mean they are dependent but I can't think of a proof.

There is another trivial example that you possibly meant to exclude, which is if $X$ and $Y$ are not themselves constant, but $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are. (for example, take $|X| = |Y| = \frac 12 \sqrt 2$ and flip two coins to determine the signs). So maybe you'd like to ask: must $X^2$ and $Y^2$ be almost surely constant? The standard way to then argue is: given that $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent, show that this implies $X^2$ is independent of itself.

Example ... $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and both have the scaled Radermacher distribution $$
P(X=1/\sqrt2) = P(X=-1/\sqrt2) = 1/2.
$$
Then $X$ and $Y$ are not constant, they are independent, but their squares are constnat $X^2 = 1/2 = Y^2$, so $X^2+Y^2 = 1$.

I tried something similar but couldn't check the independence. Don't  I need the explicit construction of probability space $\Omega$ to check it?

I guess I answered my own question. $\Omega = {1,2,3,4 }$, all points have weight  $1/4$ and $X(1) = X(2) = 1/ \sqrt{2}$, $Y(1) = Y(3) =1/ \sqrt{2} $

If $X$  and $Y$ are independent and $X^2+Y^2=1$, then $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are almost surely constant. Indeed, let $U=X^2$ and $V=Y^2$. Then $U=1-V$
and the random variables $U$ and $V$ are independent because so are $X$ and $Y$. Therefore, $1-V$ is independent of $V$ hence $V$ is independent of itself.

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and satisfy the equation $X^2 + Y^2 = 1$ almost surely. This implies that the pair $(X, Y)$ lies on the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with probability one.
Recall the definition of independence for random variables $X$ and $Y$: they are independent if and only if for all measurable sets $A$ and $B$ in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, the equation
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \in A, Y \in B) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A) \mathbb{P}(Y \in B)
$$
holds. This means that the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ can be expressed as the product of their marginal distributions.
The constraint $X^2 + Y^2 = 1$ defines a circle, and therefore, the values of $X$ and $Y$ are not independent since knowing $X$ determines $Y$ up to a sign:
$$
Y = \pm \sqrt{1 - X^2}.
$$
This relationship implies that if $X$ takes a particular value $x$, $Y$ is constrained to only two possible values, $\pm \sqrt{1 - x^2}$, contradicting the requirement for independence unless $Y$ is deterministic given $X$ (and vice versa), which contradicts the assumption of non-constancy.
In fact, you can consider a parametrization in terms of an angle $\Theta$, where $X = \cos(\Theta)$ and $Y = \sin(\Theta)$. For $X$ and $Y$ to remain independent under this parametrization, $\Theta$ would have to be uniformly distributed over $[0, 2\pi)$, and even then, $\cos(\Theta)$ and $\sin(\Theta)$ are not independent, as evident from their covariance in the standard uniform distribution on the circle.
Therefore, it is impossible for $X$ and $Y$ to be both independent and non-constant while simultaneously satisfying $X^2 + Y^2 = 1$. The relationship by the unit circle creates a dependency between $X$ and $Y$, demonstrating that any such $X$ and $Y$ must indeed be dependent.
